# How to retrieve a list of tables which are in my SAP system with ABAP program?

Tags: abap

I need to retrieve a list of tables which are in my SAP system, can someone explain how to make this? I am new with ABAP. I have to write a program for this with input field for table name and value search.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the following SAP tables to get the data:

- **DD02L** SAP Tables: information about the tables
- **DD02T** SAP Table Texts: table descriptions

By selecting the data from **DD02L** you can put additional conditions to retrieve the tables you need. Most probably you may want to restrict the query to get:

- only *custom tables*:
  ( **tabname** LIKE 'Z%' OR **tabname** LIKE 'Y%' )
- only *activated tables*, i. e. entries activated or generated in this form:
  **as4local** = 'A'
- only *database tables* TRANSP and / or *structures* INTTAB:
  **tabclass** IN ('TRANSP', 'INTTAB')

So you can start with the query:

```
  SELECT * FROM dd02l INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_tables)
     WHERE ( tabname LIKE 'Z%' OR tabname LIKE 'Y%' )
       AND as4local = 'A'
       AND tabclass IN ('TRANSP', 'INTTAB').
```

and develop it further as you need according to your requirements.

Comment: Perkeft, you're welcome.

Comment: I have other question please, I have displayed the table description (Fields and thier data type), now I have two fields one is input field and the othere is number of records. What I want to make, I select table from system and then give some number of records for exmple 10 and click some button to enrate random data in this table. How can I  make it?

Comment: @MahmoodHammood When you have any followup questions that go beyond what you initially asked, please post them as new questions. But remember that Stackoverflow is not a free programming service. We can answer questions, but we won't develop your whole application for you.

Comment: @Philipp Yes I know this. I have published the other question.